# Advanced Custom Fields in wordpress wont show on dashboard

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I just installed Advanced Custom Fields on my wordpress site.

However i cant find the edit screen on the dashboard to create new ACFs or edit them.

Anybody know why it isnt showing?

The wordpress is a fresh install of the newest version as of today. Same goes for AFC

Wordpress version: 3.5.1
AFC version: 3.5.8.1

Comment: please give the exactly version of WP and ACF.

Comment: updated versions in thread

Comment: plugin is active (from the plugins menu)?

Comment: You should have a look to the doc of the plugin (https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf) were we can read 
_Tested up to: 3.5.0_

Comment: I just tried installing version 3.5.0 and the ACF plugin. It still does not show up in my dashboard menu. Im quite confused.

Comment: With the WP 3.5.0 did you try the ACF 3.5.5?

Comment: The only version that works is the 4.0 beta. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start before installing a plugin is to check the compatibility with the WordPress version.

For this go to the plugin page
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

At the right you can check compatibility:

> **Requires:** 3.0.0 or higher
>
> **Compatible up to:** 3.5.0

At the bottom right you can also select a WordPress version and a plugin version too see if it works (from users feedback).

Comment: Apparently wordpress made some new rules and the ACF plugin is being reworked. Currently the only version i could get to work was the 4.0 Beta.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin developer is reworking the code so that it complies with WordPress' new terms/privacy.

The plugin code that is in the WordPress repository (aka: if you go to install the plugin through your admin area) DOES NOT work.

But if you go to his github page, you can download the latest working version of the plugin. Upload the .zip file to install the plugin, and that will give you the latest working version.

https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf